# laravel: odd behavior when query is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have a model

I call it this way:

```
Sight::filter(['type'=>'menu']);
```

and in model:

```
public function scopeFilter($query,$params)
{
    return $query
        ->wherePublish(1)
        ->whereIn_special(1)
        ->latest()
        ->first();
}
```

when there is one or more records, it works normally.

but when database is empty I get an odd behavior:

with `dd(Sight::filter(['type'=>'menu']))`

or

```
$query
        ->wherePublish(1)
        ->whereIn_special(1)
        ->latest()
        ->first();
        dd($query);
```

I got this result:

[image]

But with

```
dd(
$query
            ->wherePublish(1)
            ->whereIn_special(1)
            ->latest()
            ->first();
)
```

I got Null so it is right!

how can I return Null? what is my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `first()` inside of a scope - you are only meant to adjust the query by constraining it. You should call `first()` in your chain after applying the `filter()` scope. If you want to use the same syntax rather than chaining like that you would be best to define a custom static method.

```
public static function filter($params)
{
    return self::wherePublish(1)
        ->whereIn_special(1)
        ->latest()
        ->first();
]
```

Also note that in your example your scope accepts an argument (and you pass it one) but it isn't actually used in your code.

Comment: Thanks, what about `take()` and `paginate()` ? They are invalid like `first()` in scope?

Comment: `take()` is fine because again it's just adding constraints to the query. `paginate()` is not because like `get()` or `first()` it is actually performing the query.